# How is my mouse's ability attack resolved?

Tags: mice-and-mystics

We are a bit confused by how ability attacks work in Mice and Mystics, and in particular how they interact with equipped items.

Our Maginos has the ability Mystic Bolt, which states (emphasis mine):

> You may use this ability instead of performing a normal battle action. Choose a minion ... [who] is attacked by this mouse **with a ranged attack. The battle value of that attack is equal to this mouse's lore**.

Our Maginos is also equipped with an Enchanted Bow, which grants +1 to ranged attacks and has the text (emphasis mine):

> The first time this mouse attacks **with this bow** on a turn, if any [Bow w/ Star Symbol] were rolled in that attack, this mouse may attack 1 additional time with this bow.

Now, Maginos has a lore of 3, so if he uses the Mystic Bolt ability clearly the battle value will be 3.  The question is: how do we perform this attack?

Do we:

- Roll 3 dice, hoping to roll [Bow Symbol]s?
- Roll 4 dice instead of 3 due to the +1 from the Enchanted Bow?
- Ignore dice completely and just count it as an attack that hits for 3?
- Do something else?

Furthermore, if we do roll dice, does the special text from the Enchanted Bow (about sometimes making a second attack) come into play, and if so, how does the extra attack work?

Comment: Tell your Maginos to stop hogging the awesome bow and give it to Lily where it belongs. =)

Answer (score 2):

For the Mystic Bolt you roll three dice an perform a ranged attack, i.e. you want to roll bow and arrow symbols.

The bonus from the Enchanted Bow only applies, if you attack using the enchanted bow, and not Maginos' Staff, e.g. by casting said Mystic Bolt.